# Problem with SQL with LEFT JOIN for a radius search

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I'm having some problems with my radius search.
I have a table with zip codes, place names and geographical coordinates (based on OpenGeoDB).

Here is my SQL-Command:

```
SELECT main.zc_zip,
(ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
) * 6380) AS `distance`
FROM tx_sdfilmbase_geodb main
LEFT JOIN tx_sdfilmbase_geodb geo ON geo.zc_location_name LIKE '%frauenfeld%'
WHERE
(ACOS(
SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
    ) * 6380) < 20
    AND main.disabled=0
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

I get results for all locations around Frauenfeld within a radius of 20 kilometres.
However, I don't get any result for locations named "frauenfeld" - i.e. I get all surrounding places but not the searched placed itself.

How do I have to change the SQL to also get the place itself?
I tried different things, but always the same result...

Would be glad for some hints.

Greets
Stefan

**Edit to answer comments by ypercube and Matt Gibson:**

All entries in the database table have disabled=0 at the moment.

Amongst many others, I get the following results (zip, distance):

- 8552 3.7661608052471
- 8500 4.184731709915
- 8523 4.9298917004071
- 9548 4.9771821340396

Zip codes for Frauenfeld: 8500, 8501, 8502 and 8503.

Missing entries in the result would be (zip, distance):

- 8500 0
- 8501 0
- 8502 0
- 8503 0

However, the data in the geo database is correct (zip, place, latitude, longitude):

- 8503 Frauenfeld 47.557707 8.897367
- 8502 Frauenfeld 47.557707 8.897367
- 8501 Frauenfeld 47.557707 8.897367
- 8500 Frauenfeld 47.557707 8.897367

**Edit to reply to answer by kuru kuru pa:**

Thanks for your reply!
The Answer looks like this now (zc_location_name, zc_zip, disabled, distance):

```
Frauenfeld 8500 0 NULL  
Frauenfeld 8503 0 NULL  
Frauenfeld 8502 0 NULL  
Frauenfeld 8501 0 NULL  
Gerlikon 8500 0 4.18473170991499
```

Why is it NULL and not 0? Any guesses? :-)
Btw: Each result was listed 4 times (I just posted each once).

Comment: Have you checked if the location with `name LIKE '%frauenfeld%'` has `disabled=0` ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the rows you think your query *should* be finding? Also, is that the right SQL? Your question title says LEFT JOIN, but you don't appear to be using a LEFT JOIN in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query:

```
SELECT
main.zc_zip,
main.disabled,
(ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
) * 6380) AS `distance`
FROM tx_sdfilmbase_geodb main
LEFT JOIN tx_sdfilmbase_geodb geo ON geo.zc_location_name LIKE '%frauenfeld%'
WHERE main.zc_zip in(8500, 8501, 8502, 8503)
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

And then evaluate the results of `distance` and `disabled`.  Your value of your function or disabled probably isn't what you're expecting it to be.

**EDIT** (In response to null result for distance field)

```
SELECT
main.zc_zip,
main.disabled,
(ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(isnull(main.zc_lat,0))) * SIN(RADIANS(isnull(geo.zc_lat,0)))
    + COS(RADIANS(isnull(main.zc_lat,0))) * COS(RADIANS(isnull(geo.zc_lat,0)))
    * COS(RADIANS(isnull(main.zc_lon,0)) - RADIANS(isnull(geo.zc_lon,0)))
) * 6380) AS `distance`
FROM tx_sdfilmbase_geodb main
LEFT JOIN tx_sdfilmbase_geodb geo ON geo.zc_location_name LIKE '%frauenfeld%'
WHERE main.zc_zip in(8500, 8501, 8502, 8503)
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT
main.zc_zip,
main.disabled,
isnull(
(ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
)
,0) * 6380) AS `distance`
FROM tx_sdfilmbase_geodb main
LEFT JOIN tx_sdfilmbase_geodb geo ON geo.zc_location_name LIKE '%frauenfeld%'
WHERE main.zc_zip in(8500, 8501, 8502, 8503)
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

OR alternatively to using ISNULL()

modify your original WHERE to say 'WHERE distance < 20 ***OR distance is null***'

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry for the chaos with the comments (I'm not yet used to this website ;-)). I edited my first post above to give you feedback. @Matt

Comment: @Stefan -- Your NULL results on the distance column probably means that your math is trying to evaluate a null at some point.  I modified my answer for a few things you can try...

Comment: @Stefan -- BTW -- I'm not good at this kind of math, so I gave 2 potential answers.  Essentially, the ISNULL() function says 'if this thing I am evaluating is null, then output a `___`', where "`___`" is whatever you specify.  In my samples, I used a zero.

Comment: As I'm using MySQL I think ISNULL() should be IFNULL(). However, your first edit-code still delivers me NULL-results and the second code with the isnull over the whole trigonometric expression, SQL says that there's a syntax error. I checked the MySQL manual but couldn't see the error... For the last suggestion with "OR distance is null" it says "Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'".

Comment: Ok, saw the problem. I corrected it isnull/ifnull has to be around the whole distance-specification and not just within the trigonometric expression.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` checks.

I think changing the `WHERE` clause would suffice:

```
WHERE
    ( (ACOS(
          SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
          + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
          * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
      ) * 6380) < 20
      OR main.id = geo.id                          --- the PK of the table
    )
    AND main.disabled=0
```

The problem probably lies in the calculations producing something like `ACOS(1.00000001)` and yielding `NULL` when the main and the geo (`lat`,`lon`) are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, problem is already solved, just couldn't post an answer (had to wait 6 hours...)

Comment: Well, can you check what  `SELECT SIN(RADIANS(47.557707)) * SIN(RADIANS(47.557707)) +COS(RADIANS(47.557707)) * COS(RADIANS(47.557707)) *COS(RADIANS(8.897367) - RADIANS(8.897367))` gives?

Comment: And `SELECT ACOS( ... )` where `...` is the above formula?

Comment: SELECT ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(47.557707)) * SIN(RADIANS(47.557707)) +COS(RADIANS(47.557707)) * COS(RADIANS(47.557707)) *COS(RADIANS(8.897367) - RADIANS(8.897367))) is null. Sorry, I'm not sure if I get you - what exactly are you driving at?

Comment: And how can you say "OR main.id = geo.id" if you're not doing any JOIN?

Comment: @Stefan: What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table `tx_sdfilmbase_geodb` ?

Answer (score 0):

If someone someday has the same/similar problem, below the final solution for my initial problem:

```
SELECT main.zc_zip,
IFNULL(
(ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
) * 6380), 0) AS `distance`
FROM tx_sdfilmbase_geodb main
LEFT JOIN tx_sdfilmbase_geodb geo ON geo.zc_location_name LIKE '%frauenfeld%'
WHERE
IFNULL(
(ACOS(
SIN(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(geo.zc_lat))
    * COS(RADIANS(main.zc_lon) - RADIANS(geo.zc_lon))
    ) * 6380), 0) < 20
    AND main.disabled=0
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

**REMEMBER:** IFNULL is for MySQL. If you are using other versions of SQL, make sure, you use the right counterpart.